# End of record reached while expected to parse column in snowflake data loading from S3

Tags: sql, hadoop, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqoop

I am loading data from S3 stage to my snowflake table, but getting the below error :

currently the file format is csv type and delimited by escape character

End of record reached while expected to parse column '"ABC"["T_STMP":29]' If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

I have checked the data also, the value of T_STMP is getting at new line and that snowflake is considering as the end of file

```
 1234562020-11-18 
 07:41:12.336COVIDABC.comhttps://www.covide.com/bright- 
 keno/u-glass/2020/xyz-a-33/chat-pnevery goodcls F- 
 CLASS12345Very-free REl Men Rare CTR.  WATCH  
 ABCDR.  HEYA MOO  https://abc.ABCD.com/v2/abc-xyze- 
chore/sdfgsjhdfgjdhfkjdh/HIIII/HELLO-ABC_EFG_I-123- 
5.jpgCENTCANT
2010-11-15 10:12:30.083663sysadmin0001-01-01 00:00:00.0wwwww33ww- 
2a2a-1a1a-7ff6-3434343trtr36352020-15-15 10:44:05.79
```

The error is in the timestamp column that is the last third line should be like :

```
     5.jpgCENTCANT2010-11-15 10:12:30.083663
```

I know its hard to understand, but data quality is too bad!

The file is csv type and delimitted by escape character

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the COPY INTO command along with a sample of the row that has the issue?

Comment: If you share one sample records and copy command would help to figure out the issue quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error caused due to columns having 100+ varying characters length as a result timestamp and other columns was entering into new line.

The solution was to replace new line characters , carriage return characters, backspace characters for all those lengthy columns with empty string in the sqoop import job as :

```
   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(length_column,CHAR(8),''),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') as 
   length_column
```